# Calling a function using a parameter in it's name

Tags: c#, function, parameters

Can I put all of this code in one line, like "Level  + index ()" Is it possible?

I have this switch function:

```
switch(index)
    {
        case 1:
        Level1();
        break;
        case 2:
        Level2();
        break;
        case 3:
        Level3();
        break;
        case 4:
        Level4();
        break;
        case 5:
        Level5();
        break;
    }
```

as you can see, each index calls a function with the name "Level" and the index number.

Comment: There is an easier way to call a function with a parameter: Make it a parameter. `Level(index)`

Comment: Although a long time has passed since you commented, I just felt to comment just to clarify, I created multiple void functions in order to arrange data types and their values, otherwise I would have arranged the data inside the switch function, what has seemed to be uncomfortable and not aesthetic...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
typeof(yourClassCOntainingLevel1Method).GetMethod("Level"+index).Invoke(this,null);
```

`yourClassCOntainingLevel1Method` is a class name where you have `Level1` method

if it's in the same class as calling:

```
typeof(this).GetMethod("Level"+index).Invoke(this,null);
```

Comment: Your answer is actually what I need, although I get an error: "only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: It works great, all I needed to do is to declare the methods as Public.

typeof(this).GetMethod("Level"+index).Invoke(this,null); (needed to replace this as the class name also)

Answer (score 10):

Not like that, no. You *could* use delegates:

```
// Ideally make this a readonly field.
Action[] actions = { Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4, Level5 };
...
actions[index - 1]();
```

Or you could use reflection, as others have mentioned... but I'd try to avoid that if possible, especially if performance is a concern.

It does feel like an odd design though - I'd take a step back and consider whether there's a cleaner way of designing this to start with. (It's hard for us to help with that at the moment without more context.)

Comment: It does seem like a good way of calling the methods, I'll also look again through my code to check for a better option, what I actually do, is to create vectors and points in each methods that change the class properties in order to set the level.
I'm using Unity3D if that's assissting you in any way.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to achieve this is through Reflection. But it would be better to have a single Level function that takes the level as parameter:

```
public void Level(int number)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("Level"+index);
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is delegate which is answered by Jon Skeet. Also we can try using reflection but it's not the best practice due performance hit.